# How can I make Cygwin pass the home directory as a path that other applications will understand, as opposed to what amount to relational links?

Tags: cygwin, home-directory

I'm currently using Cygwin in my Z drive, but let's say I want to create and open a file in Sublime that is located in my Cygwin home directory (or somewhere in relation to it, such as through a symbolic link).

```
Manic@Babbage /cygdrive/z
$ ls ~
bin  desktop  programming  z

Manic@Babbage /cygdrive/z
$ touch ~/test

Manic@Babbage /cygdrive/z
$ subl ~/test
```

However, this simply has Sublime create a new file: `Z:\home\Manic\test`

Is there any way to get Cygwin to pass a full Windows-style path?  This is not an issue with Sublime--every other application I've tried to use this with has also failed.

Answer (score 1):

`cygpath` converts paths. Try capturing its output by `$()`:

```
subl $(cygpath -w ~/test)
```